# JavaFX delete objects from AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have

AnchorPane root

HBox in root

two VBox in HBox, each of which is nameless, new AnchorPane
and nameless Label in each AnchorPane with text

There is table, just a template does not fit me.

When I need build new table on the same spot table with new content, I make that:

```
    root.clearConstraints(hBox);
    hBox = new HBox();
    root.getChildren().add(hBox);
```

and re-create the table. But the sad thing is that the previous content from root stays. How I can remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove items from a `Pane`, you need to remove them from its children. You have a number of options to do so:

```
root.getChildren().remove(hBox); // remove a single item
root.getChildren().removeAll(box1, box2, box3); // remove all listed items (varargs)
root.getChildren().removeAll(collectionOfNodes); // remove all items in a Collection
root.getChildren().clear(); // remove all children
```

There are others as well: `getChildren()` returns an `ObservableList<Node>`, which extends `List<Node>`, so you have access to all of those methods.

Comment: Thank you! I try to find method as remove in C++ and you help me in it. I am very greatfull.